# How to create multiple websites using Webmin

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

Recently installed ubuntu server+lamp+webmin+proftpd. Set static ip. Now wanna publish multiple webistes form seperate pots on local network. Let's say my servers ip is 192.168.2.200 so site 1 will work with url 192.168.2.200:80 second 192.168.2.200:81 ... How can i configure it? Thx in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

That's not generally how you do multiple sites on the same host. It would normally be done using [Name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). There is support for this in webmin.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing Virtualmin, its a hosting control panel based on and written by the same people as Webmin.

They have got a script which will install everything from scratch and then give you a nice control panel to manage everything.  You can download it at http://www.virtualmin.com/download

The install script it at

http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a Name-based virtual hosting like what @lain said. I would suggest you follow this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/310145/help-running-multiple-websites-on-apache2/310155#310155). Although it does not show you how to set multiple websites using webmin, doing it via CLI is better.